# c#: Getting Error when calling stored procedure by EF code first with OUT Type parameter

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am calling a stored procedure which has two params and one of params is out type.

Here is the stored procedure body:

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[DetailsANDCount] 
    (@CustomerID INT = 0,
     @Counter int OUT)
AS
    IF @CustomerID <= 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT  
            Customers.CustomerID, Customers.FirstName, 
            Customers.LastName, Customers.Address1 
        FROM
            Customers

        SELECT @Counter = COUNT(*) 
        FROM Customers
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT  
            Customers.CustomerID, Customers.FirstName,  
            Customers.LastName, Customers.Address1 
        FROM
            Customers
        WHERE 
            Customers.CustomerID = @CustomerID

        SELECT @Counter = COUNT(*) 
        FROM Customers
        WHERE Customers.CustomerID = @CustomerID
    END
```

Here is my code which is throwing error:

> Additional information: The parameterized query '(@CustomerID
>   bigint,@Counter int output)DetailsANDCount @Custome' expects the
>   parameter '@CustomerID', which was not supplied.

Code:

```
private async void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var db = new TestDBContext1())
    {
        SqlParameter param1 = new SqlParameter("@CustomerID", 0);

        var outParam = new SqlParameter();
        outParam.ParameterName = "Counter";
        outParam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;
        outParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

        var customers = await db.Database.SqlQuery<Customer>("DetailsANDCount @CustomerID, @Counter OUT", param1, outParam).ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**:

```
    using (var db = new TestDBContext1())
    {
        SqlParameter param1 = new SqlParameter("@CustomerID", 0);

        var outParam = new SqlParameter();
        outParam.ParameterName = "@Counter";
        outParam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;
        outParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

        var customers = await db.Database.SqlQuery<Customer>("DetailsANDCount @CustomerID, @Counter OUT", param1, outParam).ToListAsync();
    }
```

after fixing the 2nd param name still getting the same error.

Comment: Try prefixing the name of second parameter with `@`.

Comment: after fixingthe 2nd param name still getting the same error.

Comment: Other possibility is to remove the `@` from both names. Although I've read that the names should be prefixed, maybe it is up to the SQL engine, not really sure. Sorry for that, I rarely use direct SQL queries. If that does not work, maybe it is an issue of type used. You error shows `bigint`, while your procedure uses `int`. Try specifying the type explicitly when creating the parameter.

Comment: I'm pretty sure EF just reads the result of the SELECTs and won't ever populate your out Param, you are probably better off rewriting your query without the OUT?